# Solve the following Linear Congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the following Linear Congruences:
 $$x\equiv 4\pmod {12}$$
 $$x\equiv 7\pmod {21}$$
 $$x\equiv 10\pmod {15}$$

Comment: thanks for the edit @Dimitris Nt

Comment: can anyone help me with the CRT part?

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$x\equiv4\pmod {12}\implies x\equiv0\pmod 4$ and $x\equiv1\pmod 3$

Similarly, 
$x\equiv7\pmod {21}\implies x\equiv0\pmod 7$ and $x\equiv1\pmod 3$

$x\equiv10\pmod {15}\implies x\equiv0\pmod 5$ and $x\equiv1\pmod 3$

So, $x\equiv1\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv0\pmod {4\cdot5\cdot 7}$

Use [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) as $(3,140)=1$

Comment: how r u getting the first line?

Comment: If $x=12a+4$ where $a$ is an integer, $12a+4=4(3a+1)$ and $12a+4=3(4a+1)+1$

Comment: applying CRT, i am having problem in the step  140=2(mod 3),3=?(mod 140)

Comment: @kinkar,  Here from the link, $a_1=0,m_1=3, a_2=1,m_2=140$

So, $x\equiv 0\cdot b_1\cdot 140+1\cdot b_2\cdot 3\pmod {3\cdot140}\equiv 3b_2\pmod {420}$ where $3b_2\equiv1\pmod {140}\equiv1+140\implies b_2\equiv47$

Comment: even if i write 3*47=1(mod 140) and 140*(-1)=(-1)(mod 3) while getting x=1*140*(-1)+3*47*0 is it possible?

Comment: @kinkar, $140\cdot (-1)\not\equiv(-1)\pmod 3$

Comment: here a1 is 1 and a2 is 0 isnt it?

Comment: @kinkar, does the order matter?

Comment: x=1*b1*140+0*b2*3(mod 420) gives 140*b1=1(mod 3)

Comment: a1 is a multiple of M/m1 so the order matters i think?isnt it?

Comment: @kinkar, if $a_1=1,m_1=140,a_2=0,m_2=3, x\equiv 1\cdot b_1\cdot3+0\cdot b_2\cdot 140\pmod {3\cdot420}\equiv 3b_1$ where $3b_1\equiv1\pmod {140}$ and so on

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ $ if $\,(n,m)=1\,$ then $\, x\equiv a \pmod{nm}\ \iff \bigg\lbrace \begin{eqnarray} x&\equiv\,& a\pmod{n} \\ x &\equiv\,& a  \pmod{m}\end{eqnarray}$

so, $ $ if $\,(n_i,m)=1\,$ then $\, x\equiv a_i \pmod{n_i\, m}\ \iff \bigg\lbrace \begin{eqnarray} x&\equiv\,& a_i\pmod{n_i} \\ x\equiv a_1\equiv\cdots&\equiv\,& a_k  \pmod{m}\end{eqnarray}$

In your case the common factor of the moduli is $\, m = 3,\,$ and $\, n_i\mid a_i.$